# Google Drive video embedded on website, PC and Android can play the video , iPhone cannot play the video

Tags: iphone, web, video, mp4

I use Google Drive video to embed on website. I can play the MP4 video on PC and Android phone. But I cannot play the video on iPhone. I don't know why.

Shall I convert the mp4 video to other format and code to be suitable for iphone?